# recursive functions - why not an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript

So this is apparently a valid bit of code, but I can't figure out how the second call to `power` can ever be completed if the `exponent` argument is anything besides `0`.

```
function power(base, exponent) {
  if (exponent == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
}
```

From: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jin6c.jpg

Comment: Please include valid code in the question itself, and for the love of all that you hold holy, **don't use a screenshot of your code.**

Comment: Note to editors: [An edit of the question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19992274/3) is not the right way to suggest a revised snippet. Post it as part of an answer.

Comment: Well, it *is* an infinite loop (or better: a stack overflow) when you call it with anything else but a positive integer for the exponent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the second call will keep calling with smaller numbers in exponent, until it reaches 0, and then return 1, and roll back aggregating the result ...

I think you'll have to do some reading on recursion :)

Here's a simple case of how it'll look:

```
power(2,2) 
 power(2,1) 
    power(2,0) 
       return 1 
    return 2*1 = 2 
 return 2*2 = 4
```

Taken and modified from this [page](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/).

Try this page for [an animated view of the recursion](http://www.animatedrecursion.com/simple/fact.html) (didn't work for me, it's an old page, needs java, and I don't have it installed on my machine ...)

---

**Edit:**
It was bothering me I couldn't find any simple example of this, so here's a quick console program that might help you visualize how this is working :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SO_Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int base_value = 0;
            int exponent = 0;
            string[] parts = new string[2];
            int result = 0;
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Please enter the Power to calculate in this format: x^y "
            + Environment.NewLine + "(where x is the base (int) and y is the exponent (int)."
            + Environment.NewLine);

            var temp = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(temp))
            {

                parts = temp.Split('^');
                if (parts.Length != 2)
                InvalidInput();
            }
            else
            InvalidInput();


            if (Int32.TryParse(parts[0], out base_value) && Int32.TryParse(parts[1], out exponent))
            result = Power(base_value, exponent, "");
            else
            InvalidInput();

            Console.Out.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Final result = {0}", result);


            Console.Out.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Hit any key to quit.");
            Console.Read();

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Recursive call to calculate Power x^y
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="base_value">The base</param>
        /// <param name="exponent">The exponent</param>
        /// <param name="padding">Padding, for output.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static int Power(int base_value, int exponent, string padding)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Format("{2}Power called with: {0}^{1}", base_value, exponent, padding));
            Thread.Sleep(750);

            if (exponent == 0)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("{0}{1}Base case reached, returning 1.{0}", Environment.NewLine ,padding);
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                var return_value = base_value * Power(base_value, exponent - 1, padding + "  ");
                Console.Out.WriteLine("{0}Going back in the recursion, returning {1}.", padding, return_value);
                Thread.Sleep(750);
                return return_value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Inform user about bad input and quit.
        /// </summary>
        private static void InvalidInput()
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

You can just paste and run it, and your results will look something along:

[image: outputsamuple]

**Edit 2:**
I've written an article about this, explaining in details what happens why where. You're welcome to have a look at it here : [simple power recursion, console application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/682852/Simple-power-recursion-console-application).

Answer (score 2):

Recursion only terminates when you have [edge case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_case). In the case of exponentiation the edge case is:

> n<sup>0</sup> = 1

It reads as *"any number raised to the power of 0 is 1"*.

The general case of exponentiation is:

> n<sup>x</sup> = n × n<sup>x - 1</sup>

In a mathematical language like Haskell exponentiation would be defined as follows:

```
n ^ 0 = 1
n ^ x = n * n ^ (x - 1)
```

Interestingly if you give this function a negative integer then the edge condition will never execute and it would run into an infinite loop eventually terminating in a stack overflow.

However since we only use this function with whole numbers (0 and positive integers) you will never run into an infinite loop.

Nevertheless if you use a big enough exponent you will still run into a stack overflow because computers only have so much space to store intermediate results.

In most JavaScript browsers you can calculate `2 ^ 2 ^ 14`. However if you try to calculate `2 ^ 2 ^ 15` then you get a stack overflow: http://jsfiddle.net/9chrJ/

Answer (score 1):

Observe that x<sup>n</sup> = x × x<sup>n-1</sup> and x<sup>0</sup> = 1. This is why the code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just try an example. Here's 2 to the power of 3

```
power(2,3) = 2 * (power(2,2) = 2 * (power(2,1) = 2 * (power(2,0) = 1)))
```

So:

```
power(2,3) = 2 * (2 * (2 * 1)))
```